# Obtain a share UpdateKey from LinkedIn using LinkedIn J and getNetworkUpdates() with Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Using the "Network Updates API" example at the following link I am able to post network updates with no problem using client.postNetworkUpdate(updateText).

http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted

So posting works great.. However posting an update does not return an "UpdateKey" which is used to retrieve stats for post itself such as comments, likes, etc.  Without the UpdateKey I cannot retrieve stats.  So what I would like to do is post, then retrieve the last post using the getNetworkUpdates() function, and in that retrieval will be the UpdateKey that I need to use later to retrieve stats.  Here's a sample script in Java on how to get network updates, but I need to do this in Coldfusion instead of Java.

```
Network network = client.getNetworkUpdates(EnumSet.of(NetworkUpdateType.STATUS_UPDATE));
System.out.println("Total updates fetched:" + network.getUpdates().getTotal());
for (Update update : network.getUpdates().getUpdateList()) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println(update.getUpdateKey() + ":" + update.getUpdateContent().getPerson().getFirstName() + " " + update.getUpdateContent().getPerson().getLastName() + "->" + update.getUpdateContent().getPerson().getCurrentStatus());
    if (update.getUpdateComments() != null) {
            System.out.println("Total comments fetched:" + update.getUpdateComments().getTotal());
            for (UpdateComment comment : update.getUpdateComments().getUpdateCommentList()) {
                    System.out.println(comment.getPerson().getFirstName() + " " + comment.getPerson().getLastName() + "->" + comment.getComment());                         
            }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this using Coldfusion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used that api, but I am guessing you could use the first two lines to grab the number of updates. Then use the overloaded `client.getNetworkUpdates(start, end)` method to retrieve the last update and obtain its key.

Totally untested, but something along these lines:

```
<cfscript>
    ... 
    // not sure about accessing the STATUS_UPDATE enum. One of these should work:
    // method 1 
     STATUS_UPDATE = createObject("java", "com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.enumeration.NetworkUpdateType$STATUS_UPDATE");
    // method 2
    NetworkUpdateType = createObject("java", "com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.enumeration.NetworkUpdateType");
    STATUS_UPDATE = NetworkUpdateType.valueOf("STATUS_UPDATE");

    enumSet = createObject("java", "java.util.EnumSet");
    network = yourClientObject.getNetworkUpdates(enumSet.of(STATUS_UPDATE));
    numOfUpdates = network.getUpdates().getTotal(); 
    // Add error handling in case numOfUpdates = 0
    result = yourClientObject.getNetworkUpdates(numOfUpdates, numOfUpdates); 
    lastUpdate = result.getUpdates().getUpdateList().get(0);
    key = lastUpdate.getUpdateKey();
</cfscript>
```

Comment: No go unfortunately I cannot call "getUpdateKey()" like that.  Here's the error: Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the getUpdateKey method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments.  When I change it to getUpdates() it just returns 0.  I'm also using NetworkUpdateType.valueOf("SHARED_ITEM") because I want to get my shared items.

Comment: When you use SHARED_ITEM, does it actually return anything ie what is the value of `numOfUpdates`?

Comment: Re: *there are no methods with the specified method name* Actually I think getNetworkUpdates() is returning another network object. Try accessing the underlying list. See the updated example.

Comment: to answer your first question, the value of numOfUpdates is 0 which is confusing as I know there are shared status updates

Comment: When I use the updated example here's the error: Index: 0, Size: 0 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: In your example you have "yourClientObject" and then two lines down you have "yourClient" is there a difference?  I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something there.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo (fixed now). Re: *IndexOutOfBoundsException* I posted that before you mentioned numOfUpdates is zero. The snippet needs validation or it will fail if there are no updates (like accessing an array position that does not exist). I do not know the api well enough to know why you are not getting any results though. Can you get any updates at all?

Comment: Apparently not.. but I can post updates with no problem using LinkedInApiClient.postNetworkUpdate("test 2")

Comment: Unfortunately, I have reached the end of my limited knowledge on this :/ I think the list snippet will work, but only if you can get some updates. Rather than my guessing, you might want to ask the folks on linkedinj mailing list.

Comment: Leigh.. I'm gonna go ahead and say that this does work.  As I tried using my other LinkedIn account and it does retrieve the last update key.  Yes!  Now if I can just figure out why one account works and the other does not work... both of them have a "last update" so I'm not sure what the deal is.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could provide a starting point. If you do figure out the issue, feel free to add an update to the original question for others that run into the same problem.

Comment: It appears I need to use the getUserUpdates() rather than getNetworkUpdates() but I've decided not to use LinkedIn J and replaced it with another API that I find more friendly to use called Scribe to handle the OAuth and then generate URL's from apigee.com to pass through scribe.  Simpler approach for me..

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and tip about Scribe.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use socialauth library to retrieve updates and post status on linkedin.
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth